# joomla 1.5 defining isFrontpage variable

Tags: joomla

I have made template myself and there I wanted to put `if($tmpTools->isFrontPage()) :`  as in other pre-made templates but this doesn't work because the $tmpTools is not defined. So what to do

Answer (score 0):

you can also use like this to assign the contents for your front page.

```
<?php 
    $menu = & JSite::getMenu();
    if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) { 
?>

<!--your contents here -->

<?php } ?>
```